# Compare rows SQL counting discrepancies in value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
id     firstval    secondval     
1         4            5
2         5            4
3         3            3
4         6            6
5         7            8
6         9            8
7         3            3
8         3            3
```

The first thing I need to do is count the number of times `secondval > firstval`. This is obviously no problem.

However, the thing I'm struggling with is how to then count how many times (for each instance of `secondval > firstval`) the next row satisfies the condition `secondval < firstval`

So in this example there are two rows that would satisfy the first rule id 1 & 5 and two for the second rule, the next rows id 2 and 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, @prevGreater AND secondval < firstval AS discrepancy, 
       @prevGreater := secondval > firstval AS secondGreater
FROM (SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY id) AS x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevGreater := false) AS init
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97f72c/9)

Comment: Thanks. I initialize it to `false`, otherwise the first row might be considered a discrepancy even though there's no previous row to compare with.

Comment: That probably makes more sense, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 on t1.ID+1=t2.ID -- here we join on t2.ID is t1.ID+1
WHERE t1.secondval>t1.firstval AND t2.secondval<t2.firstval
```

Now you can use COUNT statement as you want :)

Comment: What if there are gaps in the ID numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE 
(id int, firstval int, secondval int)

INSERT INTO @YourTable
SELECT 1, 4, 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 5, 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 6, 6
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 7, 8
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 9, 8
UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 3, 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 3, 3

SELECT  ID
,CASE 
    WHEN SECONDVAL>FIRSTVAL THEN 0
    WHEN FIRSTVAL>SECONDVAL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS DISCREPANCY
,CASE 
    WHEN SECONDVAL>FIRSTVAL THEN 1
    WHEN FIRSTVAL>SECONDVAL THEN 0
    ELSE 0
END AS SECONDGREATER

FROM    @YourTable
```

You could try this one.

Comment: How does this query compare consecutive rows? Look at this fiddle, it's reporting a discrepancy on row 8 when it shouldn't. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae550f/1